# No C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2015 CTP?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, roslyn, c#-6.0

I have just created a new VM on Azure (using the image provided by the Azure team from the gallery) with [CTP version of the upcoming Visual Studio 2014](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=400850) that appeared yesterday online to test it and especially to play around with new C# 6.0 features.

However, it does not provide support for C# 6.0 out of the box, for none of the language extensions (primary constructors, property initializers, safe navigation operator) work there.

[A blog entry on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp-now-available.aspx) suggests adding the following to project settings:

```
 <LangVersion>Experimental</LangVersion>
```

But this changes nothing in my console project. Even the [sample code from the second link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/06/03/visual-studio-14-ctp-now-available.aspx) doesn't compile at all.

[image: safe navigation operator is not recognized]

Do I miss something?

Comment: Do you have Roslyn installed?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Roslyn

Comment: Do I need to install it separately? It should be now an integral part of Visual Studio and I see some new features leveraged by it (like refactorings).

Comment: why do you have a space after the `()` ?  The sample code you linked to doesn't do that.

Comment: @RobertLevy I typed the code as it is, the space was added by the editor automatically without asking me, so I just left it as it is to show that the actual intent wasn't clear both to compiler and editor.

Comment: Just a side note: _It is recommended to install the Visual Studio "14" CTP on a VM, VHD, or fresh computer. There are known side-by-side compatibility issues with Visual Studio 2013._ (cited [here](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio))

Comment: @BradChristie Actually I just used the image provided by Azure to create a brand new VM with only VS2014CTP installed there, there is no any other side-by-side software whatsoever and it is running in the VM hosted on Azure. I will edit my question to add this detail, if this might be important here.

Comment: Try using "experimental" with a lower case 'e'.  We had a bug where we compared case sensitively, and may not have got the fix checked in early enough to reach the CTP.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There is a bug in the CTP where the `LangVersion` switch is case sensitive.  Try using `experimental` instead.

Comment: I confirm that it works for me, the original blog page has been updated to reflect this change too. I suggest you add the warning that this setting is case-sensitive to your blog entry too.

Comment: This option no longer works in Visual Studio 2015 preview - Invalid option 'experimental' for /langversion.

Comment: It's no longer required in VS 2015. There are no longer any "experimental" features included in the compiler that is part of VS 2015.