# How can the new C# 6.0 syntax features be used in scriptCS?

Tags: c#, scriptcs, c#-6.0

If I try to compile the following code with [scriptCS](http://scriptcs.net/) it fails compilation with a syntax error for the line containing the primary constructor (Error CS 1514 '{' expected to be exact):

```
public class MyClass(string someName)
{
    public string Name { get; } = someName;
}
```

I know that the new syntax features [have to be enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066584/no-c-sharp-6-0-in-visual-studio-2014-ctp) on a per-project basis in the first CTP of Visual Studio 2014, but couldn't find a similar setting for scriptCS (or any other information about C# 6 and scriptCS). My understanding is, that scriptCS is using Roslyn, so there *should* be a way to support those features.

So how do I *enable* the new C# 6 syntax features in scriptCS? Or isn't that possible (yet)?

Comment: I can't see anything on the list of latest commits which would implicate that ScriptCS uses newest Roslyn bits: https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/commits/dev

Comment: Good point! Although not good news.. ;)

Comment: Looks like I found [the reason](http://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=FAQ&referringTitle=Home#Scripting,%20REPL,%20and%20Executing%20Code%20Questions) scriptCS hasn't been updated: the scripting API (which is used by scriptCS) has been temporarily removed for re-design in the latest version of Roslyn.