# Enabling C# 6 in ASP.VNext projects in Visual Studio CTP2

Tags: asp.net-core, c#-6.0

I have installed Visual Studio CTP2 and created a new ASP.Net Vext project. When I tried using C# 6.0 features, it was not working. I even tried the stpes in the following link.

[No C# 6.0 in Visual Studio 2015 CTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066584/no-c-sharp-6-0-in-visual-studio-2014-ctp)

But even after this I was not able to use C# 6 in VNext projects. Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this to your project.json:

"compilationOptions": {
  "languageVersion": "experimental"
}

Comment: this option doesn't seem to work. I used the following line  --"net451" : {"compilationOptions": {"languageVersion": "experimental"} },

Comment: Try putting it at the top level not within a target framework.

Answer (score 2):

You should not add the net451 object. Use this inside the project.json file:

```
{
    "compilationOptions": { "languageVersion": "experimental"},
    "dependencies": {
    },
    "commands": {
    }
}
```

I believe they also changed the default in the latest version of the engine. so the element is actually not needed anymore if you upgrade tje kvm to the lastest version.

see https://github.com/aspnet/KRuntime/pull/512

Upgrading can be done by running kvm upgrade at the command prompt.

see https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/version-manager

HTH,
Bart