# Unable to get Roslyn end user preview to work, still uses old compiler

Tags: visual-studio-2013, roslyn, c#-6.0

I've tried installing the Roslyn end user preview to play around with some of the new C# 6.0 features, but I can't get it to work. I have Visual Studio Premium 2013 Update 3 installed. I've downloaded the Roslyn end user preview, and it installed without any problems. After restarting Visual Studio, I tried doing what has been suggested: create a new project to make it switch to the new compiler, then discard that project and open an existing project, or create another new project.

I've now tried to make a plain console project using the .NET 4.5 framework. However, I can't get any of the new C# 6.0 features to work. Neither auto-property initializers, declaration expressions, exception filters nor explicit constructors will compile for me. I've tried compiling identical code on a different computer without the Roslyn preview installed, and it gives me the same compilation errors, so it seems like it's still using the old compiler.

How can I make VS switch to using the Roslyn compiler instead?

Comment: Just to make sure: you actually tried compiling the code, right? It's not just that you're seeing squiggles from R#?

Comment: Yeah, I do get compiler errors. I tried compiling the exact same code on a different PC without the Roslyn preview, and I get the same errors, so it's definitely using the old compiler still.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enabling C# 6 in ASP.VNext projects in Visual Studio CTP2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106044/enabling-c-sharp-6-in-asp-vnext-projects-in-visual-studio-ctp2)

Comment: @IanRingrose I'm not using the Visual Studio 2014 CTP, and this is not an ASP.NET vNext project. I'm having a specific problem that the question this allegedly duplicates doesn't address, and neither of the answers to that question are relevant or helpful here. I'll edit my question to clarify that.

Comment: The new features of CTP 3 (expression-bodied function members, nameof operator, Null-conditional statement expressions) still not worked for me either.

Comment: Can you run `rcsc.exe` from the command line, out of interest?

Comment: @AlexSiepman: did you mark your project as using experimental language features per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066584/no-c-sharp-6-0-in-visual-studio-2014-ctp?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski That does work in VS2014 (not VS 2013). Thanks!!